# Get page number of a specific record

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying to find a way to get the page number of a specific record.

This is my problem, after I add a new line I reload the grid, with sorting on, the new line can end up on any page. I need to be able to find the page number of that specific record, so I can navigate to its page and select it.

How can I do that, without having to load every page until I find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see to to accomplish where you would add a new record, reload the grid and then have that displayed page be the page where the new record would be found in a sorted grid.  As a solution I think you would need to set the `reloadAfterSubmit: false`, and then generate your own reload where you would pass in (via postData) a value that would tell your controller to change the page of data to return to the jqGrid.

When the controller would receive a value in this field you would have to write some code to find which page of data the record would belong to and then pass that page to the jqGrid.

As the grid would be sorted, you could find where where that record would be in the sorted dataset and then grab that page.  If you didn't have a very large dataset you could just iterate through every page till you found the page that would contain your result, but the method would depend on how large of dataset you would have. (Ex 5 pages of records, probably acceptable to just iterate through them all, as the dataset becomes larger you will have to look into fetching the proper page of data.)

Comment: I was already using reloadAfterSubmit : false, my problem is after the reload I have no clue where my line will end up, so I need to know on what page to reload. Sorting the data locally is not a solution because the sorting is rather complex by more than 1 column so it would be quite a lot of coding. I need a way after the first reload to locate my record and load his page, I have no clue how to achieve that, other than skipping thru every page until I find it and that may take a long time and would look awful.

Comment: My post was geared around doing all the sorting and finding of the correct page on the controller and only passing the page with the result to the server.  As I stated above you could iterate through the pages, or develop something more complex based on the size of your dataset.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was hoping for a way to maybe get the already sorted data from the grid, I guess I'll have to do it the hard way.